# System-call read() blocked

Tags: c, sockets, unix, system-calls

I have a client that need to read on a socket a sequence of char sent by server.
Client read with system-call read() a socket SOCK_DGRAM.

Here the complete function with system-call read(..) inside.

```
ssize_t readLine(int sockd, void *vptr, size_t maxlen)
{
    ssize_t n, rc;
    char    c, *buffer;
    buffer = vptr;

    for ( n = 1; n < maxlen; n++ ) 
    {

        rc = read(sockd, &c, 1);
        if ( rc == 1 ) 
        {
            *buffer++ = c;
            if (c == '\0') break;
        }
        else
        {
                if (errno == EINTR) continue;
                return -1;
        }
    }
    *buffer = 0;
    return n;
}
```

The problem is that if Server send a sequence of char like this ABCDEF'\0', this client read only A and then the system-call read() go in blocking mode.
I have used Wireshark to see if server work well and it send correctly ABCDEF'\0' in a UDP packet. All ok from this point of view.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: You need to read the entire datagram at once

Comment: How can I know the dimension of datagram? Every time is different.

Comment: @ABC It's your protocol --you're deciding what each datagram contains-- so you get to decide the max. You specify how much you can receive, the pre-established max. If less was sent, you'll get less. `recv`/`read` will tell you how much was received.

Comment: Whats happens if I read more than I sent?

Comment: You can't read more bytes than the size of the datagram at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With datagram sockets, you need to read and write the whole datagram at once.

If you don't give `read` enough space to read the entire datagram, the rest of the datagram simply disappears.

```
int datagram_length = read(sockd, vptr, maxlen - 1);
if (datagram_length < 0) {
    // complain about the error
} else {
    vptr[datagram_length] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. why does it work like this?

Comment: @ABC It just does. How did you think it worked? Datagrams are different from streams.

Comment: I was thinking that it works like TCP, where I can read byte one-by-one and put them in a buffer.
Why was there the design choice to prevent reading as if it were a flow?

Comment: @ABC Well a stream socket is a flow. A datagram socket is not. You *asked* for it to not be like a flow.

Comment: @ABC If datagrams were treated like a stream, how would you know where each message started and ended? That problem exists in TCP, and has to be solved by each application protocol by manually delimiting each message. But that problem doesn't exist in UDP, because datagrams are self-contained and don't have to be delimited by applications.